# How does versioning of JavaScript files work?

Tags: javascript, jsp, caching

As per few of the answers for the question asked, 
how to force browser to reload the JS on refresh,

> Add a ? to the script's src link.
>
> For instance:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```

> or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?v1"></script>
```

I just want to know how does it work? Do i need to do any changes in my JS file as well so that it gets compatible with the new version added?
if not how does it reload JS everytime with values like **src="myfile.js?1500"**  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a trick, you pass a query string that tell to the browser he have to reload the resource from the server.

It doesn't matter what is after the question mark `?` just has to be different each time the page reloads.

You don't have to change anything on your server side, as the query string can be ignored.

Comment: oh..so it should not be static like ?1500,  shouldnt it be dynamic like counter? Eg. ?DateWithTimeSec

Comment: I think so [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40667/how-do-you-avoid-caching-during-development) there is a more detailed post.

Comment: I correct my answer, the value you put after the question mark should change each time you change the js file. So when you deploy your code in production the client will load the new version and don't stuck in cache issues. If you need to handle different version, the answer provided by @medet-tleukabiluly is good too.

Comment: ok.. so every time a new JS has to be loaded,  I can just change the  value I put after the question mark with any digit. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's should avoid issues on clients cache when deploy new features.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server that would resolve file version, here's a simple implementation

**`directory structure`**

```
 - index.js
 - node_modules/
 - version0.js
 - version1.js
 - version2.js
```

**`index.js`**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/myfile.js', function(req, res){
  var version = req.query.v || 0;
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/version' + version + '.js');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening 3000');
});
```

Demo at https://glimmer-crow.hyperdev.space/myfile.js?v=1 
change the `v` query param

Hypderdev source https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/glimmer-crow

Comment: I think you answered a different question. In your example you deal with different versions of a js file that coexists and are all valid, you have just to address the proper version for features you need. But if you are developing, you change the same file and you need that this file will loaded from the server each time you test it.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini you can disable caching in browser developer tool, [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NWLQNT1.png)

Comment: Yes, but how when you go in production?

Comment: In production you have to use caching, as everything must work fast, and you don't need versions in production, as it must be minified and bundled

Comment: It's not exact, you need versions in production as long as you need to deploy new feature or bug fixing, and to do so, you need the clients to invalidate the cache. Or, as I mentioned it before, if you need more versions available for different apps.